# How to test Next.js app with svg imports as component using vitest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, next.js, vitest

I use vitest to test Next.js app following the official example [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-vitest/).

I get error saying 'InvalidCharacterError: "../../company-logo.svg" did not match the Name production'. Finally I figured out that the image was because of svg imported as components. When I removed svg imports as components, it worked fine.

I am using `@svgr/webpack` to load svg as components in my Next.js 13 app. I tried adding `vite-plugin-svgr` to `vitest.config.ts` but it does not work.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), svgr()],
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
});
```

Any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, I also use Next13 I finally fixed it by using `vite-plugin-magical-svg` with a target `react` into my vite.config.js

```
plugins: [graphql(), magicalSvg({ target: 'react' })]
```

Hope it will wirk for you !